# Python, Connecting to Module TM1Py SSL Error

Tags: python

I am trying to connect to TM1Py via python.

```
with TM1Service(address='address', port=port, user='user', password='pass', ssl=True) as tm1:
    content = tm1.cubes.cells.get_view_content(cube_name='CM', view_name='Annual', private=True)
    print(content)
```

I am getting error:

```
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='address', port=port): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/Configuration/ProductVersion/$value (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: SysCallError(-1, 'Unexpected EOF')")))
```

Does anyone know how to get around this error?

Answer (score 2):

I made your code work on my environment by changing the method get_view_content(which is depreciated) by execute_view.

```
from TM1py.Services import TM1Service
       
with TM1Service(address='myserver/localhost', port=8080, user='nimda', password='pomme', ssl=True) as tm1:
    content = tm1.cubes.cells.execute_view(cube_name='log', view_name='testTM1Py', private=False)
    print(content)
```

If you're directy on the machine where your TM1 server is running put 'localhost' if you do it remotely you have to pass the server name instead of 'localhost'.
The "port" argument is the HTTPPortNumber in your TM1s.cfg file.

I hope it can resolve your issues.
If you have more questions post them here.

Comment: Hey thanks for this. TM1 Server is not  the machine I am using. Do you k now how to where to find the TM1s.cfg file? I am guessing this would be for whoever setup the tm1 server.

Comment: Also for `myserver/localhost` you mean one or the other right? not both.

Comment: Hi @excelguy. the tm1s.cfg file is in your ..\data\.. repository for a "normal" tm1 server. But the good practice is to put it in a single repository. So you have to find the repository where your TM1/PA objects are (cubes,dimensions, processes, ...) and look for it somewhere in this area. yes it  one .  your server adress or localhost. Not hte both.